# How can I fix error "InvocableMethod methods must be in version 33 or higher"?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

I tried to get a value from flow.

This is my code which cause error "InvocableMethod methods must be in version 33 or higher":

```
@InvocableMethod
public static List<List<Opportunity>> getOppIds(List<String>Ids) {
    return new List<List<Opportunity>>();
}
```

Comment: Please check an API version of the given apex class. It must be higher then 33 as it said in a error description

Comment: Thanks, now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a ClassName.cls-meta.xml that accompanies your class file when you are using SFDX or metadata API to manage your code base. This includes specification of the API version used for that class.

The equivalent information is also available in the Salesforce Setup UI along side the class's code within Custom Code > Apex Classes. In editing a class through this UI there is a "Version Settings" tab to adjust the value.

You need to make sure that the API version is set to 33 or higher.